# Updating item property in ListView

Tags: c#, .net, listview

I am trying to figure out how to update a Object's property in a ListView after render. For an example, let's say that the ListView is DataBound to a collection of Employees. Each row displays the information of the employee. After the table is loaded, I needed to say "If an employee name = [RON] then change it to text [RONALD]".

I currently was thinking I could foreach the ListViewDataItems in the ListView, and go from there, but am stuck.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
foreach(ListViewDataItem entry in lvProjectModeratorEntries.Items)
{
    //I need to find the div where the firsName is 
    //displayed, and run my logic to update it.

}
```

I also thought I would get it through entry.DataItem but am stuck at that point.

Comment: When I get to the items, it is always saying the are "read only". I thought doing entry.Data casted as the object so: ProjectModerator = (entry as ProjectModerator).FullName == "Ronald", but that doesn't do it. Anyways, thanks again, and I will keep looking into this.

Comment: Maybe I just have to do it in databind, unless I use jquery or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you could use the [INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on your Employee model. In your listview item template, bind the text to the Employee's property that you wish to display. Then you can change your Employee objects.

Comment: I only want to change them dynamically for display purposes, but not in the database. So, we have EmployeeID = 0, and Name = "Unknown Employee" for these types. In this one instance, we want it to "Display" Contractor, not Unknown Employee. I know I should add or modify the database design for it, but we can't for certain reasons. Wouldn't this only be useful to actually modify the object entity, not just dynamically change the displayed value?  I am asking in an honest manner.

Comment: You wouldn't have to change the database. Just add the logic in your view model to handle the translation from database data to what you wish to display.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. It would also be only in some cases, other cases I still need to display "Unknown Employee". I see what you are saying. Thanks.

Comment: That's the beauty of the MVVM pattern. You can protect the data in your models while interpreting the data in various ways in your view model. Just glad I could help. :)

Comment: You know, we are taking on a new project, and everyone is jumping on to MVC. First time I have done it. Thanks again, as I was not aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

to find each item in a Listview you can loop like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < lvProjectModeratorEntries.Items.Count; i++)
{
    int ii = 1;
    MessageBox.Show(lvProjectModeratorEntries.Items[i].SubItems[ii].Text);
    ii++;
}
```

Comment: I think I will try this out for now, and then later try to update the model for how bergmeister explained, as I understand where he is coming from, to try it out.

Comment: Getting error ListViewDataItem does not contain def or extension subItems.   Let me look into the input you both mentioned, and I will update shortly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Using your own code:

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in lvTest.Items)
{
    if (item.Text == "John")
        item.Text = "John is gone";
}
```

That should give you a start on how to do things, yet I don't recommend it. There are more elegant and code-sustainable solutions. Have you thought about binding the listview to a List and make all the necessary business logic in the List, instead of the actual view?

Comment: I agree completely on finding more elegant way. That is why I am having the issue. lol  But I don't think would work either. It would be looking for the "TEXT" value of the DataItem, where the data item is actual an ProjectModerator object. Unless I mistaken.

Comment: If you're using M-V-VM you shouldn't even be accessing the items directly, instead read them from the collection, and since they're bound to the actual view, updating occurs automatically.